# Mail Merge renaming file to value in word document

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hi I have word document that has a bunch of files that need to be broken up seperately per page. I have found a Mail Merge Macro that does everything I want and merges it to individual files except it does not rename the file the way I am looking to. I am unsure how to get it to.

I am unsure if this possible but here goes nothing. I want the mail merge to look through the document and take the Employee ID integer that is in the file then rename the file to be that integer.

Ex: The page has all the information, then inside each page it says: Employee ID: 123452
Is there a way to have the merge take the Employee Id and put it as the filename?

My end result would just look like: 123452.doc with each each file will be individual

https://word.tips.net/T001538_Merging_to_Individual_Files.html

```
 Sub BreakOnSection()
'Used to set criteria for moving through the document by section.
Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection

'A mailmerge document ends with a section break next page.
'Subtracting one from the section count stop error message.
For i = 1 To ((ActiveDocument.Sections.Count) - 1)

    'Select and copy the section text to the clipboard
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy

    'Create a new document to paste text from clipboard.
    Documents.Add
    Selection.Paste

    'Removes the break that is copied at the end of the section, if any.
    Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1

    ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\Users\test\Desktop\mailmerge"
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=
    ActiveDocument.Close
    'Move the selection to the next section in the document
    Application.Browser.Next
Next i
ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: See *Split Merged Output to Separate Documents* and, better still, *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* in the **Mailmerge Tips and Tricks** thread at: https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html

Comment: @macropod I did look through that mail merge but the files are already merged. I ultimately am trying to split each word document and rename the file to be one of the integers from the file.

Comment: My previous comment referred you to *two* topics in that link. The first is for splitting such files.